# Етимологія слова "Мистецтво"

Tags: етимологія

[Стаття у Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) наводить таку етимологію:

> Українське слово «мистецтво» походить від німецького Meister (майстер), яке в свою чергу походить від латинського Magister (навчитель, начальник), що в свою чергу, вірогідно, утворене шляхом поєднання слів magis («великий») та histor знавець, умілець, згодом — актор (histrion). Етимологічно цей термін співзвучний з біл. мастацтво, а також старопольським misterstwo, і в українську мову був позичений відносно недавно. Створення цього слова приписують також редакторам часопису «Основа», або Олені Пчілці.

[Етимологічний словник](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) у 7 томах має статтю "мистець":
[image: Стаття мистець]

Статтю "майстерний" не знайшов, тож взяв статю "майстер", етимологію якого виводять з німецької Meister, яке в свою чергу походить від лат. magister:
[image: Стаття майстер]

Тобто перехід від мистецтва до Meister словник обережно вказує як "мабуть пов'язаний".

Питання в мене таке: чи правда мистецтво походить від нім. Meister? Якщо ні - яка в цього слова етимологія.

Comment: Деякий розбір на [ua_etymology](https://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/77484.html). Себто від польського [Misterstwo](http://www.staropolska.pl/slownik/index.php?nr=75&litera=M&id=1074).

Comment: @Follower, а польське _[mistrz](//pl.wikisource.org/wiki/Słownik_etymologiczny_języka_polskiego/mistrz)_ (у _mistrzostwo_) в свою чергу, здається, виводять від _[majster](//pl.wikisource.org/wiki/Słownik_etymologiczny_języka_polskiego/majster)_.

Comment: Дуже наврядчи що від німецького слова, бо німецькою мистецтво буде Kunst і походження воно має зовсім інше.

Comment: @ovnia Мається на увазі німецьке слово Meister, версію щодо походження від слова Kunst я взагалі не пропонував.

Comment: @follower, хм, поглянув уважніше, там у коментарях ціла теорія. Мовляв, слово було створено напівштучно авторами/редакторами журналу «Основа» (причому спочатку не зовсім у такому написанні й не зовсім у такому значенні). А потім отримало підживлення від сусідства з гніздом _метикувати_.

Answer (score 1):

Схоже питання було на іншому українознавчому [форумі](https://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/77484.html) і ось про що там йшлося:

> Вважається (**про слово "мистецтво**) запозиченням з польського misterstwo (sztuka, mistrzostwo,
>   від mistrz). Слово мистецтво досить пізно з’явилося в українській
>   мові, вперше засвідчено в журналі «Основа», 1862.
>
> З польської походить і західноукраїнське мистець, яке під впливом
>   метикувати видозмінилося у Наддніпрянській Україні та літературній
>   мові на сучасне митець. Також походить від misterstwo, бо навряд чи
>   можна виводити безпосередньо від відомого у староукраїнській книжності
>   мистръ.
>
> Небездоганно (**про виведення слова з польського mіsterstwo у
>   фонетичному відношенні**), але це слово було, що найімовірніше,
>   результатом осмисленої роботи над словником колективу журналу
>   «Основи». В одному номері (№1, 1862) з’явилося як мистецьтво (у такому
>   написанні), так і мистець. Не так часто буває, що слово можна точно
>   датувати. Але ще довго мистецтво конкуруватиме зі штукою; і сьогодні
>   зустрічається в деяких стилістично виправданих випадках. Можна згадати
>   як курйоз відоме глузування над українською мовою у Тургенєва:
>   «Храматыка е выскусьтво правыльно чытаты ы пысаты».
>
> Білоруське ж мастацтво-мастак, можна припустити, виникло ще пізніше,
>   вже під впливом української літературної мови.
>
> Погортав «Основу» і знайшов цікаві свідчення словотворення. Спершу,
>   виявляється, була ідея передавати так: Спеціалистъ — Мітець.
>   Спеціальность — Мітецьтво. (пропозиція М. Левченко, 1861, №7). Через
>   кілька номерів зустрічається в офіційному журнальному словнику Мистець
>   — мастер, Мистецьтво — мастерство. Ще кілька номерів по тому словом
>   митець перекладається Артист, умілець (здається, незалежно від перших,
>   П. Єфименко). Цікаво, що можна вирахувати навіть прізвища авторів.
>   Спершу штучне (чудова гра слів!), слово отримало своєрідне підживлення
>   від сусідства з гніздом метикуватий. Метець у зн. «майстер, мастак»
>   зустрічається вже у виданні творів Гребінки, які вийшли того ж 1862
>   року.

Тобто "мистець", яке ми бачимо у [ЕСУмі](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1989/EtSlUkrM_1989.pdf) також походить з польської мови. І якщо ж ми глянемо на польське "[mistrz](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/mistrz)", від якого було утворено "misterstwo", то побачимо, що вона справді походить від німецього "Meister".

До речі, із журналом "Основа", де вперше було вжите це слово можна ознайомитися [тут](https://booktracker.org/viewtopic.php?t=43399).

Answer (score 0):

Безклубенко С. Д. *Нариси загальної теорії мистецтва*:

> Українське слово мистецтво (як і біл. мастацтва) вважається запозиченням зі ст.-пол. misterstwo (від mistrz), що походить од нім. Meister (майстер), котре виводиться з лат. Magister (навчитель, начальник), утвореного шляхом поєднання слів magis («великий») та histor («знавець», «умілець», згодом — «актор»).

[image: магістр1]
[image: магістр2]